# Show progress bar in Blender 2.8 exporter

Tags: python

Does Blender 2.8 have default Progress Bar in GUI (not in console) to show exporting progress for my exporter plugin (something similar to DrawProgressBar from Blender.Window in Blender 2.49) ?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This seems like a "How do I" with very little research

Comment: I've tried 'context.window_manager' and ProgressReport, but both are just for console output, so no GUI progress bar during export.

Comment: It's ugly, but [apparently you can monkey-patch existing UI elements](https://blog.michelanders.nl/2017/04/how-to-add-progress-indicator-to-the-info-header-in-blender.html) to show a progress bar like the one for rendering.

Answer (score 2):

This is all I've found so far:

```
import bpy

win = bpy.context.window_manager

win.progress_begin(0, 100)

for i in range(1,100) :
    win.progress_update(i)

win.progress_end()
```

**Update**

According to the [source code](https://developer.blender.org/rB1c502d83167b24eb0b9e55b4254463fc6331e5ed) this was intended to be a real progress bar, but that was back in 2013, unfirtunately it seems to have fallen into obscurity.

Comment: I've tried this too, but it doesn't show any GUI progress bar. The 3dsmax and Maya have built-in GUI progress bar, I believe the Blender also had one before version 2.5.

Comment: It will show the little black square with the progress counter.

Comment: Yeah, with a number and disappears when you move the cursor :). Useless.

Comment: According to the blender source this was intended to be more that a "useless" cursor.  See source commit https://developer.blender.org/rB1c502d83167b24eb0b9e55b4254463fc6331e5ed

Comment: Thanks for details. According to 'progress_update' body it only updates the cursor :), 115: WM_cursor_time(wm->winactive, val);

Comment: The pertinent comment in the code is "89: placeholder data for final implementation of a true progressbar" ... so the intent was there, alas the implementation was not.